# React raw html displays in the output

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on the markdown-previewer that will help me to learn REact). 
I use a "Marked" library *(A full-featured markdown parser and compiler, written in JavaScript)*. After I had input text in the textarea - Raw HTML displayed in the div id="outputText". What should I do to make browser display rendered html.
Here's the code:

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      _text: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      _text: marked(e.target.value)
    });
  }

  componentDidMount

  render() {
    return ( < div className = "headDiv" >
      < textarea onChange = {
        this.handleChange.bind(this)
      }
      id = "inputText"
      rows = "25"
      cols = "100" / >
      < div id = "outputText" > {
        this.state._text
      } < /div>
            </div >
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < Input / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @martinarroyo thanks for the link, Im sorry but I havent found that. If it helps I will remove the question

Comment: If that is the solution to your question, I'd flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: @martinarroyo Yes it helped. Should I remove the question or mark it as duplicate?

Comment: A duplicate should do. Already done :)